# Ebook library management for OS X

Tags: osx, document-management, ebooks

I am looking for a Calibre alternative that works on OS X as I find the ugliness of Calibre too much.

I don't mind paying a little bit for a commercial solution that would allow me to manage my PDF and EPUB files on folders, which probably I would continue to keep on a Dropbox folder in order to be able to load them from the iPhone/iPad.

Comment: - [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/in/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html) Free - [Alfa Ebooks Manager](http://alfaebooks.com/features) Free and Paid(with additional features) - [BookONO E-book Manager](https://etopian.com/software/bookono/) Free - [Delicious Library](http://www.delicious-monster.com/) Paid - [Lucidor](http://lucidor.org/lucidor/) Free - [Scida](http://getscida.com/) Paid - [Google Play Books](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-play-books/id400989007?mt=8) Free

Comment: Any requirement besides syncing and being nice-looking?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's own iBooks application should work very well for this. It's free, pretty, syncs with iOS devices, and can open PDF's and ePubs.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots on OS X and iOS? Thanks! I know the question lacks details but see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality